# Deep Learning Model apply for prediction real values

Tags: python, dataset, regression, deep-learning

I have a dataset following structure:

```
Dataset
    Trainig_Set
          Folder_ID_1
          Folder_ID_2
          Folder_ID_3
              .
              .
              .
          Foder_ID_125
```

Each folder has no equal images, i.e, `Folder_ID_1 = 600, Folder_ID_1 = 750, ... , Folder_ID_45 = 450`.

I has label value following structure:

```
{"Folder_ID_1": 12.1, "Folder_ID_2": 9.1, "Folder_ID_2": 10.5, ... , "Folder_ID_125": 8.5}
```

***Question:***
(1) How can apply Deep learning Model for prediction such like real value?